# How to return values from a QDialog instance in Python?

Tags: python, pyqt4, pyside, qdialog

I'm trying to open a QtGui.QDialog, request a set of values from the user, then return the values after "save" is clicked.

The following code should run without modification.

```
import sys
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
import numpy as np

class MyQDialog(QtGui.QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyQDialog, self).__init__(parent)

        ## Default values

        self.eta1 = 1.0
        self.eta2 = 1.0

        ## Create labels and buttons

        frameStyle = QtGui.QFrame.Sunken | QtGui.QFrame.Panel

        self.eta1__QL = QtGui.QLabel(str(self.eta1))
        self.eta1__QL.setFrameStyle(frameStyle)
        self.eta1__QBtn = QtGui.QPushButton("Set eta1:")

        self.eta2__QL = QtGui.QLabel(str(self.eta2))
        self.eta2__QL.setFrameStyle(frameStyle)
        self.eta2__QBtn = QtGui.QPushButton("Set eta2:")

        self.cancel__QBtn = QtGui.QPushButton("Cancel")
        self.save__QBtn = QtGui.QPushButton("Save")

        self.eta1__QBtn.clicked.connect(self.set_eta1)
        self.eta2__QBtn.clicked.connect(self.set_eta2)
        self.cancel__QBtn.clicked.connect(self.cancel)
        self.save__QBtn.clicked.connect(self.save)

        ## Set layout, add buttons

        layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        layout.setColumnStretch(1, 1)
        layout.setColumnMinimumWidth(1, 250)

        layout.addWidget(self.eta1__QBtn, 1, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.eta1__QL, 1, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.eta2__QBtn, 2, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.eta2__QL, 2, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.cancel__QBtn, 3, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.save__QBtn, 3, 1)

        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.setWindowTitle("Thank you for reading!")

    ## Button functions

    def set_eta1(self):
        self.eta1, ok = QtGui.QInputDialog.getDouble(self,
                "Change of variable", "Rate (type 1):", 0.1, 0, 1e8, 3)
        if ok:
            self.eta1__QL.setText(str(self.eta1))

    def set_eta2(self):
        self.eta2, ok = QtGui.QInputDialog.getDouble(self,
                "Change of variable", "Rate (type 2):", 0.3, 0, 1e8, 3)
        if ok:
            self.eta2__QL.setText(str(self.eta2))

    def cancel(self):
        self.close()

    def save(self):
        return self.eta2, self.eta2


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    edit_params__QD = MyQDialog()

    if edit_params__QD.exec_():
        value1, value2 = edit_params__QD.save()

        print 'Success!', value1, value2
    else:
        print 'I shouldn\'t print, but I do.'

    sys.exit()
```

Thank you very much for your time! Any suggestions for improvement are greatly appreciated!

Comment: The save button has absolutely no function in your programm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the return values in this line:

```
def save(self): 
    return self.eta2, self.eta2
```

to: return self.eta1, self.eta2

In main (of course your need to import sys):

```
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
edit_params__QD = MyQDialog()
edit_params__QD.exec_()
if edit_params__QD.result() == 0:
    value1, value2 = edit_params__QD.save()
    print('Success!', value1, value2)
```

Add the second connection to what you already have:

```
self.save__QBtn.clicked.connect(self.save) 
self.save__QBtn.clicked.connect(self.close)
```

I hope this helps.